# Accessing values within arrays and objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, magento, iteration

I'm struggling accessing data within Objects and arrays:

[image: Objects]

I've tried the following;

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
   echo $orders;
   echo $orders["Order"]
   echo $orders["Order"][0]->OrderId;
   echo $orders["Order"][0];
   echo $orders["Order"]->OrderId;
   echo $orders["Order"]->OrderId;
}

foreach($orders as $key => $value) {
   echo $value;
}
```

I'm trying to process orders which I can then input into our Magento programmatically.

Comment: which key-value pair you want to access?

Comment: Can you do a `print_r( $orders )` before the first foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

according to your screenshot it should work this way:

```
foreach($orders->fields['Order']['value'] as $order){
    $OrderId = $order->fields['OrderId']['value'];
}
```